# Two kind of UITableViewCell , Two Different Arrays from JSON . How to Populate the UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying hard to get the desired display . I have looked for the Stackoverflow for the same kind of question . But there scenario is very different then what i want to build . Please go through my description before marking as duplicate or Down vote it .

My JSON Hierarchy :

**Array of Checklists :**

> 1. id
> 2. name
> 3. task count
> 4. Array of tasks
>
>    1. id
>    2. checklist_id
>    3. name
>    4. completed
>    5. comments

Now I have 2 kind of **UITableViewCell** . I can't use **Sections** as I am using it for different purpose. 
I need to populate the UITableView As :

1 **TableViewCell** should be checklist then respective tasks and if I can achieve this . I want to add 3rd kind of **UITableViewCell** for Adding task . It should come after all tasks of respective checklist.

Comment: In what form you want to populate your tableview ?? What would be the sequence of the 2 types of cell ? Can you show wireframe of the screen ?

Comment: First Kind Checklist then respective tasks . For e.g.
indexpath.row == 0 so checklist then tasks . then again after all tasks for that checklist is done .checklist UITableViewCell is done.

Comment: Simplest thing you can do is edit your tableview array. Add identifier   like isCheckList or isTask or isNewCell to respective cell. And then you can identify the type and display accordingly

Comment: @JayGajjar: Sorry dude, I am new ,Can you please elaborate your solution a lil bit.

Answer (score 0):

Made a Universal Array for Name , ID and all the attributes and set null where the attribute was not present . Thanks @Jay Gajjar for the approach.